# Problem with recording and saving video with CAMERA MAUI

Tags: c#, android, video, camera, maui

I have created a method that allows you to record videos and save them using the appropriate function. The problem is that it doesn't save videos, I've tried various methods including that of the CAMERA MAUI guide and none seem to work.

I tried both creating the mp4 file first as in this method and without creating it (as the guide does):

```
 private async void TakeVideo(object sender, EventArgs args)
 {
     try
     {
         if (!isRecording)
         {
             isRecording = true;
             foreach (FileInfo file in cacheDirectory.GetFiles())
             {
                 file.Delete();
             }
             if (cacheDirectory.Exists)
             {
                 cameraView.Camera = cameraView.Cameras[selectedCamera];
                 string fileVideoPath = Path.Combine(cacheDirectory.FullName, "Video.mp4");
                 File.Create(fileVideoPath).Close();
                 var result = await cameraView.StartRecordingAsync(fileVideoPath, new Size(1920, 1080)); //not work
                 IconVideo.TintColor = Orange;
             }
         }
         else 
         { 
             isRecording = false;
             var result = await cameraView.StopRecordingAsync();
             IconVideo.TintColor = Red;
             string namefile = await Shell.Current.DisplayPromptAsync("Rinomina Video", "Inserisci nome video: ", "CONFERMA", "ANNULLA");
             if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(namefile))
             {
                 namefile += ".mp4";
                 string localFilePath = Path.Combine(dcmiDirectory.FullName, namefile);
                 var fileTrovato = cacheDirectory.GetFiles().FirstOrDefault();
                 File.Copy(fileTrovato.FullName, localFilePath, true);

                 VideoSource = localFilePath;
             }
             cameraView.Camera = cameraView.Cameras[selectedCamera];
             MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
             {
                 await cameraView.StopCameraAsync();
                 await cameraView.StartCameraAsync(new Size(1920, 1080));
             });
         }
     }
     catch(Exception ex)
     {
         await Shell.Current.DisplayAlert("ERRORE", ex.Message, "OK");
     }
 }
```

I create directories like this, and it works:

```
private async void CreateCacheDir()
{
    try
    {
       string dcmiDir = Path.Combine(FileSystem.CacheDirectory, "DimasiDCIMCache"); 
       dcmiDirectory = Directory.CreateDirectory(dcmiDir);
       string cacheDir = Path.Combine(dcmiDir, "Cache");
       cacheDirectory = Directory.CreateDirectory(cacheDir);
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
        await Shell.Current.DisplayAlert("ERRORE", ex.Message, "OK");
     }
}
```

**UPDATE**

In the new version 1.4.6 they resolved the problem.